# Querying in Google bigQuery work slow

Tags: database, search, google-bigquery

I have a table which contains nearly a million rows. Searching for a single value in it takes 5 sec and around 500 in 15 seconds. This is quite a long time. Please let me know how can I optimize the query?

My query is:

```
select a,b,c,d from table where a in ('a1','a2')
```

Job id  : stable-apogee-119006:job_ClLDIUSdDLYA6tC2jfC5GxBXmv0

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Any answers to how can i optimize?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Help others help you by giving the queries that you are trying to run. For BigQuery engineers, having the job IDs for some past queries may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for adding the job ID. Unless someone beats me to it, I'll take a look tomorrow morning (Pacific time).

Comment: What billingTier did you used with your query? Are you using legacy or standard SQL? Is your table partitioned? Bigquery is bigdata tool for terabyte scale, so don't expect answers smaller than 3 seconds there won't be even for small data. But it will be really fast for huge data.

Comment: Legacy sql. Table partition according to time or any other field? No we have just 1 table for 10 lac rows.

Comment: any updates on how to partition table?

Comment: You didn't mention that "searching for a simple value" meant that you were using an analytic function over the contents of the table (based on the job ID that you shared). It's expected that analytic functions won't be as fast as a simple scan with a filter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "500 it takes 15 secs" but I ran some tests against our database trying to simulate what you are running and I got some similar results to yours

*(my query is slower then yours as it has a `join` operation but still here we go):*

```
SELECT
  a.fv fv,
  a.v v,
  a.sku sku,
  a.pp pp from(
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    hits.product.productsku sku,
    hits.page.pagepath pp
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([40663402.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -3, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -3, 'day')))
  WHERE
    1 = 1 ) a
JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([40663402.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -3, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -3, 'day')))
  GROUP EACH BY
    fv
  LIMIT
    1 ) b
ON
  a.fv = b.fv
```

Querying for just one day and bringing just one fullvisitor took BQ roughly 5 secs to process 1.7 GBs.

And when I ran the same query for the last month and removed the `limit` operator it took ~10s to process ~56GB of data (around 33 million rows):

[image]

This is insanely fast.

So you might have to evaluate your project specs. If 5 secs is still too much for you then maybe you'll need to find some other strategy in your architecture that suits you best.

BigQuery does consume seconds to process its demands but it's also ready to process hundreds of Gigas still in seconds.

If your project data consumption is expected to grow and you will start processing millions of rows then you might evaluate if waiting a few secs is still acceptable in your application.

Other than that, as far as your query goes, I don't think there's much optimization left to improve its performance.

(*ps: I decided to run for 100 days and it processed around 100 GBs in 14s.*)